# How to sanitize data or input

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I have already applied validation on all input ex: email etc last thing which is not understandable to me is how to sanitize unwanted character on input. Please see the [noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oUWF.png) image and look for object key containing noise.

## TASK

Remove unwanted character key from given  [dataObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcUss.png).

Please do note that this data set is generated from hardware which is connected to our platform.

Comment: Please read **[ask]** and then update the question to include the required information.

Comment: `myString.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/i, '')` -> leaves only alphanumeric symbols, nothing more

Comment: @ Justinas not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to filter-out non alphanumeric characters, here is an example:

```js
var mystr = "dfh%$&$*&gjhfdsj0_14"

console.log(mystr.split("").filter(ch =>/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/i.test(ch)).join(""))
```

The task is to check every key in your `data` Javascript Object and rename it according to the above example

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(old_key => {
        new_key = old_key .split("").filter(ch =>/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/i.test(ch)).join("")
        if (old_key !== new_key) {
            Object.defineProperty(data, new_key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data, old_key));
            delete data[old_key];
        }
});
```

Comment: still getting those characters in key